# Splitting a Large JSON File Into Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a large JSON file that's based on about 1000 pages of (paginated) data. I'd like to split the JSON file about 100 into separate files, separating them based on the page. What's the best way to go about splitting a large JSON file into multiple files? Thank you!

Comment: what is format of this JSON? Is it prettified? Best formatting for this task is first and last line are open/close an array, and one line per page data...

Comment: It's bit difficult to store that large files in browser. For this make a set-up at back-end fetch json data based on page.

Comment: @vp_arth: yes, it's prettified.

Comment: @chandu: that's specifically why I want to split it into multiple files.

Comment: @shmuli : where you are planning to store all the splitted files? again its in browser right?

Comment: @chandu: local storage.

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON formatted as followed:

```
[
  {page: 1},
  ...
]
```

Then you can to use console editors like awk/sed with `csplit` tool.

Anything like this:

```
cat 1.json
arth@arth-MIT:~$ cat 1.json
[
 {page: 1},
 {page: 2},
 {page: 3},
 {page: 4},
 {page: 5},
 {page: 6},
 {page: 7},
 {page: 8},
 {page: 9},
 {page:10},
 {page:11},
 {page:12},
 {page:13},
 {page:14},
 {page:15},
 {page:16},
 {page:17},
 {page:18},
]
arth@arth-MIT:~$ rm xx* ; SIZE=$((10+1)) ; cat 1.json | awk "ORS=NR%$SIZE?RS:\"\n], \n[\n\"" | csplit - $(($SIZE+2))
126
100
arth@arth-MIT:~$ cat xx00
[
 {page: 1},
 {page: 2},
 {page: 3},
 {page: 4},
 {page: 5},
 {page: 6},
 {page: 7},
 {page: 8},
 {page: 9},
 {page:10},
],
```